# display user typed number as superscript in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am creating an iOS app in which I want to display the user typed number as an superscript  for e.g. if user presses 4, then `e^4` must be displayed on the textview.  Help me if anyone has the suggestion  thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@"\u2070 \u00B9 \u00B2 \u00B3 \u2074 \u2075 \u2076 \u2077 \u2078 \u2079"
```

Should be `0 - 9` respectively ( I Tested ) Except 1 2 and 3 are a little larger.

Comment: need to display user typed number as a superscript in textview

Comment: For that, you can use `-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`
 delegate method of `UITextView`. and `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` to replace your text.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me...

declare this at beginning

```
static char * superscript[] = {"⁰", "¹", "²","³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶","⁷", "⁸", "⁹"};
```

then while accessing it

```
generate1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"b%@ = a%@ ==> %.1f",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:subscript[degree_term]];
```

here "degree_term" is the superscript that u want...